# How to split this array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

How to split the following array so that i can get lon and lat points only every time ? In perl Script  ?

```
[{"lon":77.594376,"lat":12.971606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.604376,"lat":12.980606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.674376,"lat":12.981606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.684376,"lat":12.982606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.744376,"lat":12.983606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.784376,"lat":12.990606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.804376,"lat":12.991606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.824376,"lat":12.995606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.874376,"lat":12.997606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.894376,"lat":12.999606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null}]
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a JSON library as well, but if it's just a one off, you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/"lon":([^,]+),"lat":([^,]+)/) {
        push @data, [$1, $2];
    }
}

print Dumper \@data;

__DATA__
[{"lon":77.594376,"lat":12.971606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.604376,"lat":12.980606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},"lon":77.674376,"lat":12.981606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},"lon":77.684376,"lat":12.982606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},"lon":77.744376,"lat":12.983606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},"lon":77.784376,"lat":12.990606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},"lon":77.804376,"lat":12.991606,bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},"lon":77.824376,"lat":12.995606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jk":null},{"lon":77.874376,"lat":12.997606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},"lon":77.894376,"lat":12999606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null}]
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        '77.594376',
        '12.971606'
      ],
      [
        '77.674376',
        '12.981606'
      ],
      [
        '77.744376',
        '12.983606'
      ],
      [
        '77.804376',
        '12.991606'
      ],
      [
        '77.874376',
        '12.997606'
      ],
      [
        '77.894376',
        '12.999606'
      ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [JSON library in Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm) to parse your JSON string. After that, you will have an array of hashes that you can iterate over and extract the lat/lon values.

Comment: But my input is coming from text file here . Can i use JSON library in Perl?

Comment: Just read the file into a string and use the JSON library on this string.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `JSON` library as suggested by *j0nes*, here's a one-liner that prints `lat` and `lon` given on standard in:

```
perl -MJSON -le '$, = "\t"; map { print $_->{lon}, $_->{lat} } @{JSON->new->decode(<>)}'
```

Output:

```
77.594376   12.971606
77.604376   12.980606
77.674376   12.981606
77.684376   12.982606
77.744376   12.983606
77.784376   12.990606
77.804376   12.991606
77.824376   12.995606
77.874376   12.997606
77.894376   12.999606
```

Explanation:

- `-MJSON` loads the package.
- `$,` sets the field delimiter to tab.
- `map` maps the print command onto each hash in the array reference returned by the decode function.

Answer (score 2):

As others already stated, using a library for this task would be much better (see my code example below). If you do it like flesk, you have to make sure, the `lat` comes always after the `lon`. A little bit more robust could be this, but note I'm splitting the data in chunks that aren't valid `JSON` strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# split in (invalid) object parts
my @chunks = split /},/ => <DATA>;

# iterate over chunks
for (@chunks) {

    # extract latitude/longitude
    my $lon = /"lon":([^,]+)/ ? $1 : 'UNKNOWN';
    my $lat = /"lat":([^,]+)/ ? $1 : 'UNKNOWN';

    # print data
    print "lon: $lon, lat: $lat\n";
}

__DATA__
[{"lon":77.594376,"lat":12.971606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.604376,"lat":12.980606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.674376,"lat":12.981606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.684376,"lat":12.982606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.744376,"lat":12.983606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.784376,"lat":12.990606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.804376,"lat":12.991606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.824376,"lat":12.995606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.874376,"lat":12.997606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.894376,"lat":12.999606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null}]
```

Output:

```
lon: 77.594376, lat: 12.971606
lon: 77.604376, lat: 12.980606
lon: 77.674376, lat: 12.981606
lon: 77.684376, lat: 12.982606
lon: 77.744376, lat: 12.983606
lon: 77.784376, lat: 12.990606
lon: 77.804376, lat: 12.991606
lon: 77.824376, lat: 12.995606
lon: 77.874376, lat: 12.997606
lon: 77.894376, lat: 12.999606
```

A far better and simpler solution would just use the [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON 'decode_json';

# decode input
my $objects = decode_json <DATA>;

# iterate over objects and print data
printf "lon: %f, lat: %f\n", $_->{lon}, $_->{lat} for @$objects;

__DATA__
[{"lon":77.594376,"lat":12.971606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.604376,"lat":12.980606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.674376,"lat":12.981606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.684376,"lat":12.982606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.744376,"lat":12.983606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.784376,"lat":12.990606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.804376,"lat":12.991606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.824376,"lat":12.995606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.874376,"lat":12.997606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null},{"lon":77.894376,"lat":12.999606,"bfg":18000,"xyz":null,"jky":null}]
```

Output: the same as above.

So, *please* don't do it by hand unless you're absolutely knowing what you're doing! :)